# what could be the payload data type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am running a graphql mutation:

```
interface SignInReponse {
  loginEmail : {
    accessToken: number;
  }
}

 const [login] = useMutation<SignInReponse>(LOGIN);

let submitForm = (email: string, password: string) => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    login({
      variables: {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      },
    })
      .then(({ data }: ExecutionResult<SignInReponse>) => {
        if (data !== null && data !== undefined){
        dispatch({ type: "login", payload: data.loginEmail.accessToken })  
        setTimeout(_ => {
          setShouldRedirect(true);
        }, 2000)
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
  }})
```

My login reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    token: null
};

export const loginReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload } :any) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "login":
      return {...state, token: payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I want to change `any` data type in `{ type, payload } :any` and be more specific.

However, I don't understand what's the correct way to find/use the right data type. I have already tried using SignInResponse but that doesn't work since type/payload aren't mentioned in it.

EDIT:

I also tried this:

```
export const loginReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }: {type: "login", payload: string })
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

```
TypeScript error in /helpers/privateRouting.tsx(7,32):
Property 'token' does not exist on type 'never'.  TS2339
```

---

I modified things like this but it still gives an error:

actions/login.ts:

```
const LOGIN = 'LOGIN'

export interface LoginAction {
    type: typeof LOGIN
    payload: string;
  }
```

allActions.ts:

```
import { LoginAction } from './login';

export type AnyAction = LoginAction
```

Login Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    token: null
};
export const loginReducer = (state = initialState, action: AnyAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      return {...state, token: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Reducer index.ts:

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    login: loginReducer,
});
```

PrivateRouting:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...rest }: any) => {
  const routeComponent = (props: any) => {
    if (store.getState().login.token) {
      return React.createElement(component, props);
    } else {
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/404' }} />;
    }
  };
  return <Route {...rest} render={routeComponent} />;
};
```

Error:

```
Property 'token' does not exist on type 'never'.  TS2339

     5 | export const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...rest }: any) => {
     6 |   const routeComponent = (props: any) => {
  >  7 |     if (store.getState().login.token) {
```

Store index.ts:

```
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

let store = createStore(persistedReducer);
let persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

I am using the privateRoutes like this:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <div>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}></Route>
              <Route path="/404" component={Error404Page}></Route>
              <PrivateRoute
                path="/add"
                component={AddUserPage}
              />
              <Redirect from="*" to="/404" />
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: For this particular action it is `{ type: "login", payload: number }`, but it is better to make it [a bit smarter](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript)

Comment: `export const loginReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }: {type: "login", payload: string }) => { ... ` And if it is a string you should fix it in your `SignInReponse`

Comment: The error you've added occurs in a place where the state is consumed you have to add types for your state shape as well. Your example does not tell us where your `store` comes from and what its type is.

Comment: Do you import it directly to `PrivateRoute`?

Comment: Take a look at your `PrivateRoute` component, this line `if (store.getState().login.token) {`, where variable `store` comes from? I don't see `useStore` hook or passing it as a prop.

Comment: Ah you're right. I had also imported it in the privateRouting file ```import { store } from '../../store';```so shouldn't getState work?

Comment: So you need to add types there (btw it is better to access `store` using a hook or connect HOC). `const store = createStore<S, A, {}, {}>(...)` where S is a type of your entire state and A is a union type of all your actions.

Comment: I tried adding a type to the createStore and also combine reducers but got errors in both. Can you take a look at this sandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-shape-q2kz0?file=/src/App.tsx @Shlang

Comment: I don't see any point it turning this question that was actually answered into "How to use typescript in redux" lesson, there are many of them including the [official documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript)

Comment: If you take a look at the commented out sections, you'll see I did attempt after going through a bunch of tutorials but I just couldn't get around it fully @Shlang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common theme when using Redux with TypeScript. You should use a union type exported from some big main `actions.ts` file in an important place. For example:

```
// somewhere/ComponentOne.tsx
export default ComponentOne = () => stuff;

export interface OneAction {
  type: 'ONE_ACTION';
  payload: string;
}
```

```
// all-actions.ts
import { OneAction } from './somewhere/ComponentOne';
import { AnotherAction } from './somewhere/AnotherComponent';

export default type AnyAction = OneAction | AnotherAction;
```

Then in your reducer:

```
import { AnyAction } from '../../all-actions.ts';

function loginReducer(state = initialState, action: AnyAction) {
  // stuff
}
```

Now your reducer knows exactly what it's getting and the type safety is perfect. [This article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-structure-your-typescript-react-redux-app-877d1eba1c1e) explains it much better than I can and is *highly* worth a read.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. Probably some minor mistake. Could you please see the updated qs?

Comment: @a125 What's the type of your store's state? Shouldn't it just be `store.getState().token`, not `store.getState().login.token`?

Comment: @a125 Can I see the rest of your code? I don't know what the store's state type is. If it's the same as the type of `initialState` then this error makes no sense because `initialState` has a property `token` on it.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-shape-q2kz0?file=/src/App.tsx Here, I created a sandbox.

Comment: @a125 Does this work for you? https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-shannon-0ivez?file=/src/store/reducers/index.ts

Comment: Works perfectly! Could you please also guide me about what would be the best way to implement logout from the exit icon? Should I use the same ```tokenReducer```and add a ```LOGOUT```case in the switch? For deleting the payload in the state, should I use filter? But where exactly?

Comment: @a125 Yes, you would use the same tokenReducer since the action affects the same piece of data (the token). I don't see where you would have to use filter or any array stuff, just set the token to null like it was at the beginning. For example: ```export const tokenReducer = (
  state: IState["token"] = null,
  { type, payload }: AppAction
): typeof state => {
  switch (type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return payload; case "LOGOUT": return null;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution:* Add an interface for `initialState`, and use it as the generic type parameter for `combineReducers`.

```js
interface StoreState {
  token: string | null
}
const initialState: StoreState = ...;
export const rootReducer = combineReducers<StoreState>({...})
```

*Reasoning:* The error occurs at `store.getState()`, and redux has type declaration for `getState()` like

```js
/**
 * @template S State object type.
 */
export interface Store<S> {
  //...
  getState(): S;
  //...
}

export const createStore: StoreCreator;
export interface StoreCreator {
  <S>(reducer: Reducer<S>, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<S>): Store<S>;
  <S>(reducer: Reducer<S>, preloadedState: S, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<S>): Store<S>;
}
```

(you can find the above in `node_modules/redux/index.d.ts`.)

So it looks like our code didn't specify the generic type parameter `S` for `Store<S>`. Looking at the code above, we see that typescript should know `S` in `Store<S>` if we specify it in `createStore` call, or better, infer `S` from the function param `reducer: Reducer<S>`.

So the goal now is to specify `S` for the(any one) param in `createStore(persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer))`. I'm missing the type of `persistReducer` here, but I suppose it gets `S` from `rootReducer`.

So the goal becomes specify `S` for `combineReducers({login: loginReducer});`, while `combineReducers` has a signature of:

```js
export function combineReducers<S>(reducers: ReducersMapObject): Reducer<S>;
```

Oh! The result of `combineReducers`(`Reducer<S>`) can only get `S` from explicit specified type param in `combineReducers<MyType>(...)` (no refering from function param like some functions mentioned above). So we specify it.

Comment: I started getting overloading errors just at this step ```combineReducers<StoreState>``` Also, I am not sure if I fully understand the second step that you did. Could you please have a look at this qs & the sandbox? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61227075/implement-login-logout-using-reduxtypescript