# implement logout using Redux+TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a login page, which redirects to a private `/panel` page if the login is successful and an accessToken is returned. I'm using Redux store to check for the token in the privateRoute component.

**Problems I'm facing:**

- I want to implement logout from the `/panel` page using the exit icon. If I try to add another reducer in the combined reducer, I get TypeScript errors.
- What would be the best way to implement logout from the exit icon? Should I use the same `tokenReducer` add a `LOGOUT`case in the switch? The accessToken from the store needs to be deleted somehow. For deleting the payload in the state, should I use filter? But where exactly?
- Since I'm using persist, the accessToken remains in the local storage. So even if I reload the codesandbox (or terminate and re-run my app in localhost), the next time, I will be able to access `/panel`without even logging in.

**CodeSandbox:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-shannon-0ivez?file=/src/store/reducers/index.ts

Email: c@c.com

Password: check

The only main difference is that instead of manually writing the accessToken, in the original code, I am running a GraphQL mutation. If the login is successful, an accessToken is returned and dispatched like this:

```
 dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: data.loginEmail.accessToken });
```

where `loginEmail`is the mutation and `accessToken`is the string returned. If someone could copy the Sandbox and guide me, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

For the "where to store the token" part: As we know we usually store a `sessionID` or something in the cookie as an identifier for the server to keep the user's session. If we need to store some other token, mostly we still use cookie, like how [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf) and [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) treat `csrf-token`: store in cookie, send it in header when sending an xhr request, or place it as a hidden input in a form (so it gets sent along with other form fields).

Don't quite get other parts of the question but, I'd say structure your redux store code however you like, as long as they are clean, readable, easy to maintain.

Comment: I'm not asking where to store the token. I'm saying how to delete it. Basically, my question is just asking how I can implement the logout. Maybe you can have a clearer picture from the codesandbox.